# Validate JWT generated from WSO2 IS through Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, wso2

I am in the process of developing a Spring Boot application that will expose multiple GET REST APIs to retrieve certain things from the database. The "constraints" that will be used for the selection are located within the JWT's claim.

It was decided that the WSO2 IS will be utilized to create the JWT. This token will then be passed to the REST APIs (through the Authorization header) as it will contain useful information within the claim (e.g. dob, role, etc.).

I tried to find examples on how to integrate the JWT Token created by the WSO2 IS but can't find something that will work for my case. The closest implementation/explanation I found is available [here](https://github.com/Buddhimah/wso2is-rolebased-authz).

More specifically, the backend will have to extract the JWT's claim, get the necessary information, and use it to retrieve DB objects. However, the backend is agnostic from the user information as the user credentials are stored in a different place and managed by the WSO2. (thus cannot use the AuthenticationManagerBuilder)

So my understanding is that the backend should validate the JWT. The question is whether this is feasible as the backend since it does not hold the user information. If yes, are there are any posts that could help me with the implementation? If no, what is the alternative?

Comment: As I am understanding, the claims contains everything you need to apply your business logic. Is that right? If so, you can see the claims as an HashMap<String, String>, so you could retrieve those informations and use them everywhere in your controllers, even if your backend does not know anything about the user.

Comment: @GregorioPalamà thanks! So that means that I will don't need to validate the JWT right? Just use it to obtain the information.

Comment: Well, for security purposes, the JWT must always be validated, but you can validate it against WSO2 IS, via the introspection endpoint: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/invoke-the-oauth-introspection-endpoint/. Otherwise, you risk to accept any token you receive, and that's not exactly secure